# Create a issue or bug in JIRA using jenkins pipeline whenever test cases fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jira, jenkins-groovy

I tried multiple ways to create the task or bug in JIRA using Jenkins pipeline however its not working. Its doesn't show any log about jira issue creation. Please help me on this

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Build and Test') {
        steps {
            // Build your project and run tests, generate XML test report
        }
    }
    stage('Publish JUnit Test Results') {
        steps {
            // Publish JUnit test results
            junit 'core/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
        }
    }
    stage('Create Jira Issues') {
        steps {
            // Use the JiraTestResultReporter to create Jira issues
            jiraTestResultReporter(
                configs: [
                    jiraStringField(fieldKey: 'summary', value: 'Issue from Jenkins'),
                    jiraStringField(fieldKey: 'description', value: 'Issue from Jenkins'),
                    jiraStringArrayField(fieldKey: 'labels', values: ['Jenkins', 'Integration'])
                ],
                projectKey: 'JiraKey',
                issueType: 'Task',
                autoRaiseIssue: true,
                autoResolveIssue: false,
                autoUnlinkIssue: false
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}